# how should define an optional constraint in a query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a simple question. I want to write a Query on MySql. So I wrote this store procedure to get some thing:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `attributes_fetchall`(p_origin_id bigint, p_status char(1))
begin
select * from attributes where status = p_status and origin_id = p_origin_id;
end
```

but I want to get all rows with `status=p_status` when `p_origin_id = null`. I mean I can get this query when `origin_id = null` :

```
select * from attributes where status = p_status
```

and when origin_id != null return this query:

```
select * from attributes where status = p_status and origin_id = p_origin_id;
```

How should I write this store procedure that can handle this 2 in a one query?

Comment: Nothing is equal to or not equal to null(or any other aritmetic operator) ,unless null is a string in which case it should be quoted, it is either IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional test to check which select to use

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `attributes_fetchall`(p_origin_id bigint, p_status char(1))
begin
if p_status is null then
 select * from attributes where status = p_status and origin_id is null;
else
 select * from attributes where status = p_status and origin_id = p_origin_id;
end if;
end
```